# PHP code not working - custom error message printed

Tags: php, html, database, variables, echo

So, I'm trying to get a login page to work but I have a few errors.  Here's a breakdown of what's happening and what's not working.

1. The page loads properly, and everything can be seen.
2. If I input a correct username & password combo, I know it's been received as the page simply turns blank.  However, the echo statements don't print.

   ```
   echo "You have been logged in as ".$firstName." ".$lastName.", (".$user.").";   
   echo "<a href = 'GroceryOrder.php'>Confirm</a>";
   ```
3. When something incorrect is inputted into the user and password fields, instead of printing the error message, the page just reloads, with no new message printed.
4. My button to create an account works.

Any help would be much appreciated!  Here's the body of my code so far (and my database is set up properly, I've already checked).  Also, I called session_start(); at the top of the doc before my head info.

Comment: Are you having that whole HTML inside a single string? `:o`

Comment: It's because I want that called just as is when the page is opened, and recalled if certain things are inputted incorrectly. Is there a better way to set it up then? *Also there's a php variable that I want to change depending what is inputted.

Comment: Better to use `include("page.inc")` or something. The main reason is, it's difficult for the developer to change anything inside that. Agree?

Comment: First thing I see when opening a file with this code: 
Notice: Undefined index: loginBtn in root\index.php on line 41

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to better format it? As previously mentioned, it's just because I want to continue calling and re-printing that html code, with edited error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace  `if ($_POST['loginBtn']){` with  `if (isset($_POST['loginBtn'])){`

This will check if "submitBtn" has ANY value set, instead of checking if the value submitted with the name "submitBtn" is just "true"
(wich it doesn't seem to be in your case)

Comment: This helped get rid of an error saying loginBtn was undefined, but didn't help to get things working correctly overall.

Comment: You should keep the HTML out of the PHP and vice versa, for better readability. It is somewhat hard to spot any errors

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is how you are checking the `POST`. Use:

```
if (count($_POST)) // This checks if there's anything being posted to the page.
```

Comment: Where exactly would I change this in my program?  (Sorry, still learning)

Comment: @MandyLB Replace `if ($_POST['loginBtn']){` with the above.

Comment: I changed it to if (isset($_POST['loginBtn'])) as suggested by @Minzkraut and that got rid of another error. Would using count be better in this situation? All I want to do is check if the button's been pressed.

Comment: @MandyLB Since that's not set, it **will not** work. Try mine and tell me if it works?

Comment: I changed it and it still gave me the same issues; not printing the internal echo statements, and not printing the error messages.

Comment: @MandyLB Can you make a [C9](https://c9.io) environment and replicate it?